# Visual FoxPro 7.0 SQL запрос к полю возвращает только 1 символ

Tags: sql

При запросе к таблице "partners", происходит выборка кодов и наименований партнеров, поле "shortname" после отработки запроса содержит только 1 символ из всего наименования.
Функция SUBSTR() также при любой заданной длине возвращает 1 символ.

```
SELECT code as partner_code, shortname ;
FROM partners;
WHERE code IN (SELECT DISTINCT part_code FROM partners_list);
INTO CURSOR output
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ALLTRIM() не помогает, CAST() не отрабатывает.

Comment: Разобрался. Проблема была в том что я обновлял значение наименования в другой таблице.. Я подготовил поле для наименования и в запросе оно выглядело как `"" as partner_shortname`. При обновлении этого поля туда записывался только один символ. Я изменил его на `"                         " as partner_shortname` (отвел для него 25 пробелов) и запрос отработал на ура.

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста, свой комментарий как ответ.